# A module is working in Anaconda prompt, but not in Spyder

Tags: python, import, anaconda, spyder, osmnx

I have been fighting with this problem for hours now, and it's a kind of complicated one.
I'm on windows 7, Python 2.7, Spyder 3.2.6
I tried to install [OSMNX](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) through `cygwin`, however I faced many issues. Finally managed to install it through windows cmd.
Through the `anaconda prompt`, I could import the `osmnx` with no error. 
 
However, I'm trying to import it in spyder, but I keep receiving: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-2b99ab66aebb>", line 1, in <module>
    import osmnx

ImportError: No module named osmnx
```

What is exactly wrong here? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you created any other environments? Run `import sys` `print( sys.executable)` on both Spyder and Anaconda prompt and see if they both return the same path.

Comment: @Simon I run what you said. The Spyder and Anaconda run different paths. How can I move the module from the Anaconda path to Spyder path? Since I already installed many modules which I run on Spyder.

Comment: Not really sure how this problem has come about.  Have you got a virtual environment activated that you forgot to deactivate?

Comment: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: @Simon I never dealt with any environments (Honestly, I don't know how to do that). So basically I didn't change any default thing.

Comment: @Simon Thank a lot for the helpful link and hints. So now here is the issue: in spyder I have two environments, one has `osmnx`, and the other doesn't. Is it possible to move the module from an environment to another? or is it possible to specify to which environment I want to install a module?

Comment: No.  You could clone the installation to build an entirely new, but exactly the same as the previous one.  Or you would have to install it again.

Comment: but if I install it again, it would be exactly at the previous environment, that's why I asked about specifying the environment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169851/discussion-between-simon-and-philippos).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the use of different environments for your anaconda prompt and your instance of spyder, as mentioned by @Simon. This problem and the different available solutions are reviewed here: [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder)

You can solve the problem as follows. Provided that you have the package `spyder-kernels` already installed in your Anaconda prompt environment, run the following command in Anaconda prompt:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

and copy the path returned to your console. Then, in Spyder go to **Tools>Preferences>Python interpreter**. Here you will see two options under *Select the Python interpreter for all Spyder consoles*. Check the second option and paste the path you copied from the Anaconda prompt. Close Spyder and open it again and now the `import module` command should work.

By doing this, Spyder will basically use the Python interpreter from the environment in which you have installed the new modules.

Comment: Thanks, 
It helped for me, with adding spyder kernel module to python (since spyder maybe wants spyder kernel module, to work)

Comment: I had to choose the appropriate interpreter as explained in this answer. If you're having a venv inside a conda env, ensure that you choose the interpreter of the venv.

Answer (score 4):

You need to sync the environment variables/path for both .

Just go to the anaconda promt and enter the command

```
> conda install spyder
```

It will automatically prepare the environment. Following that, just open up spyder and execute your code.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. I have installed the Spyder and Jupyter inside the conda environment. After that it's working fine for me.

```
source activate my_conda_env
conda install spyder
conda install jupyter notebook
```