# Python module requests working in anaconda prompt but not in windows 10 command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I try to execute the following python code

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://www.bbc.com')
```

I get the error message

```
raise SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL "
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

Same python code executed in the anaconda prompt just works fine. So I found this link: [A module is working in Anaconda prompt, but not in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038651/a-module-is-working-in-anaconda-prompt-but-not-in-spyder)

Executing the command given in the stackoverflow post I get the path:
`C:\Users\x1\Anaconda3\python.exe`
Calling this path from a windows 10 command line and executing the code above still raises the error.

Comment: Is the Anaconda version of Python in your environmental variables?

Comment: Yes, I added the mentioned Path. It doesn't even work if I put the whole path (C:\Users\x1\Anaconda3\python.exe to the windows command line to start Python.

Comment: What is the path to the script that you're using to start the anaconda prompt?

Comment: I'm using the desktop icon from the windows start menu to execute anaconda prompt. The destination is given as %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\x1\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\x1\Anaconda3

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue (same error message related to the requests module) with a virtual environment of `python 3.8.3` on a `windows 10` virtual machine and no admin rights. The solution for me actually was the `PATH` environment variable as described in the answer of Paul Stevens here: [Requests (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.") Error in PyCharm requesting website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module) .

So I added the following paths to the environment variable `PATH` for my user:

1. Open `environment variable` for my user (to access the environment variable just type `environment variable` in your windows search bar.)
2. Select the `PATH` variable and klick `edit`
3. Add the following paths (replace `<path>` with your actual path, for me it would be something like `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3` etc.):

   - `<path>\Anaconda3`
   - `<path>\Anaconda3\scripts`
   - `<path>\Anaconda3\Library\bin`
4. Open a new command window
5. Run your script

And then it magically worked for me.

Btw the `print(sys.executable)` command would show me the same information in the command and in the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where running a python script as a scheduled task would raise this error (whereas running the script from Anaconda Prompt or from Spyder would work as expected). It appears to be a permissions issue. Try to start the Windows Command Line as an administrator (right-click and Run as Administrator). It should work.

To achieve this as a scheduled task, instead of calling a batch file which then called python and then the script, call python directly from the task and add the script as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Anaconda Prompt in Admin Mode
- Run this command conda install -c anaconda requests
- Install that package
- Then run your code again. It should work now