# New to anaconda and spyder. using different sys.executables

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

For some reason when I install a package through Anaconda, it is not available in Spyder.  When I execute the following command in anaconda and in spyder I get different files.

Anaconda:

```
import sys; sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\onp1ldy\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\deeplearning\\python.exe'
```

Spyder:

```
import sys; sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\onp1ldy\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\deeplearning\\pythonw.exe'
```

Can anyone help me with this?  I am not sure what to do...

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is with python and pythonw because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe), Do you have more than one python version installed ? If yes which one comes first in the PATH ?

Comment: I don't have python in PATH. I installed Anaconda/Spyder, and python comes with it. I also installed the package - torch - through Anaconda Prompt (run with administrator rights). When run in the Anaconda Prompt console, the package is included and I am able to use it without error; when I include it in Spyder, it is included, but it gives error at the same operation used in console "'torch' has no attribute rand :/"

Answer (score 2):

**By Default:** You can **control** which one of the executables will run your script. Such as, when opened from Explorer by choosing the right **file_name** like:

**1.** `python.exe` is a terminal-based (**console**) application to **run** and **lunch** CLI-Type Python-scripts.

> `*.py` files are by default associated (invoked) with `python.exe`

**2.** `pythonw.exe` is a GUI-based app for lunching Graphical User interface-(No_UI_at_all_Scripts)

> `*.pyw` files are by default associated (invoked) with `pythonw.exe`

TO SUMMARIZE AND COMPLEMENT MY OPINION:

First of all, Python-Binary that you're trying to run doesn't have `Package` installed. It does have a directory path named as `package_name` like **torch** at the search path of modules, and it is being treated as a [Package namespace](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) like for me:

```
torch.Tensor(5, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'Tensor'
```

For your current python binary, you need to install your `package` correctly. Visit Reference: [Home-Page](https://pytorch.org)

```
python3.7 -m pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.2.0.post3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
python3.7 -m pip install torchvision
```

More importantly, replace the `pip` or `pip3` as the Home-Page instructions use with `python3.7 -m pip;`. In the end, don't forget to include `python3.7` to be the full path to your Python binary.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in spyder and see if you can access the package.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('pip install numpy', shell=True)

import numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your description the problem may be connected to the Python interpreter that you are using in Spyder. There is a similar issue on Stack Overflow at this url:

[Issue on Anaconda and Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038651/a-module-is-working-in-anaconda-prompt-but-not-in-spyder)

You can try the solution proposed by Bremsstrahlung.

Hope this can help you.