# Module installed in Anaconda, same interpreter with Spyder yet Spyder gets "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, python-module

I have installed the netcdf4 library through

```
conda install -c anaconda netcdf4
```

And it shows up fine on my conda environment:

[image: Conda envs]

However, when I try to import it in Spyder, I am getting an

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netcdf4'"

I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038651/a-module-is-working-in-anaconda-prompt-but-not-in-spyder). As you can see below, both the interpreters are the same (in tools/preferences it's set as python.exe, not pythonw.exe):

[image: interpreters]

Yet when I try to import the netcdf4 module, it says there is no module named this.

[image: whyyy]

Any ideas what the cause could be? It's been two days of trying to get Anaconda to work and it has not been a smooth experience at all, really close on giving up on Anaconda as a whole.

Added per request, a screenshot of my entire IDE. Notice in the console I ran `pip install netcdf4`, where it says I already installed it. Directly below is importing the module and the error:

[image: IDE]

And how the console looks on each startup:

[image: console]

Comment: check in which environment is spyder running in. By default it works in the `base` environment, you have to change the environment to `visan`

Comment: How do you check this? I run spyder from the cmd in the same environment. Visan is also the active environment I run spyder from

Comment: Check both are having same Virtual Environment. If same install netcdf4 using pip. pip install netCDF4

Comment: In the bottom right corner, there will be `conda: base` mentioned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Spyder in virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170468/how-to-run-spyder-in-virtual-environment)

Comment: @SuganeshKumar I have tried to install via this method, but it says netcdf4 is already installed

Comment: @Junkrat I do not see anything in the bottom right corner, and that is the exact same way I have installed my virtual environment

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your entire spyder ide?

Comment: @Junkrat I added an extra image with some additional info in the console. I added an extra image how it looks like when starting up spyder, because it seems compared to other screenshots I'm missing some info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226917/discussion-between-junkrat-and-b-quaink).

Answer (score 0):

The docs/tutorial used stated

```
import netcdf4
```

While now it is case sensitive

```
import netCDF4
```

Such a simple fix..